# sheeting excel sheet after user id using a for loop

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

[**Data**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrMoA.png)

Given the data above, I want to be able to name each excel sheet by the id. But the code only names sheet after last id.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

df_dummy = pd.read_csv('dummy.csv') 

id_store = df_dummy['id'].unique()

for i in id_store:
    print (i)
    workbook_dummy = xlsxwriter.Workbook('store_dummy.xlsx')
    worksheet = workbook_dummy.add_worksheet('store {}'.format(i))
    workbook_dummy.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the XlsxWriter Workbook object before the for loop.

Comment: Now, it only adds a sheet for the first id.

Comment: and workbook_dummy.close() at the end of the script, outside the loop

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).